# Connection between Python & Postgresql Docker Containers Issue

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, fastapi, psycopg2

I've been researching this particular issue and I've tried many suggestions from SO. Unfortunately, here I'm.

**What's the problem?**

I have so far 2 docker containers. One for Python code, and the second for Postgres.

Here's my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    container_name: howdyserver
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: backend.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./server/app/:/app/
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  database:
    container_name: howdydb
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - 5430:5430

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here's my **.env** file:

```
POSTGRES_USER = "howdyadmin"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "howdy"
POSTGRES_SERVER = "localhost"
POSTGRES_DB = "howdydb"
POSTGRES_PORT = 5432
```

And here's my **Dockerfile** for Python container.

```
FROM python:3.11.1-slim

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

COPY ./alembic.ini /app/alembic.ini

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app/

CMD ["uvicorn","main:app","--host=0.0.0.0","--port=8000","--reload"]
```

Now after running `docker-compose up -d --build` and `docker-compose up` I receive the following output from the Postgres:

```
howdydb     | 
howdydb     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
howdydb     | 
howdydb     | 2023-05-16 21:55:12.333 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit
howdydb     | 2023-05-16 21:55:12.334 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
howdydb     | 2023-05-16 21:55:12.334 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
howdydb     | 2023-05-16 21:55:12.344 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
howdydb     | 2023-05-16 21:55:12.370 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-16 21:51:12 UTC
howdydb     | 2023-05-16 21:55:12.380 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

And from Python container

```
howdyserver | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
howdyserver | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
howdyserver | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles
howdyserver | URL:  postgresql://howdyadmin:howdy@localhost:5432/howdydb
howdyserver | INFO:     Started server process [7]
howdyserver | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
howdyserver | Pending jobs:
howdyserver |     No pending jobs
howdyserver | ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
howdyserver |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
howdyserver |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3275, in raw_connection
howdyserver |     return self.pool.connect()
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 455, in connect
howdyserver |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1271, in _checkout
howdyserver |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
howdyserver |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 719, in checkout
howdyserver |     rec = pool._do_get()
howdyserver |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
howdyserver |     with util.safe_reraise():
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
howdyserver |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
howdyserver |     return self._create_connection()
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 396, in _create_connection
howdyserver |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 681, in __init__
howdyserver |     self.__connect()
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 905, in __connect
howdyserver |     with util.safe_reraise():
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
howdyserver |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
howdyserver |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
howdyserver |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 636, in connect
howdyserver |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in connect
howdyserver |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
howdyserver |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
howdyserver |   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
howdyserver | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
howdyserver |   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
howdyserver | 
howdyserver | 
howdyserver | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
howdyserver | 
howdyserver | Traceback (most recent call last):
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 677, in lifespan
howdyserver |     async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 204, in __aenter__
howdyserver |     return await anext(self.gen)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/app/main.py", line 32, in lifespan
howdyserver |     worker_client.start_working()
howdyserver |   File "/app/worker/client.py", line 26, in start_working
howdyserver |     self._scheduler.start()
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/background.py", line 35, in start
howdyserver |     BaseScheduler.start(self, *args, **kwargs)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 163, in start
howdyserver |     store.start(self, alias)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 68, in start
howdyserver |     self.jobs_t.create(self.engine, True)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 1149, in create
howdyserver |     bind._run_ddl_visitor(ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3225, in _run_ddl_visitor
howdyserver |     with self.begin() as conn:
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
howdyserver |     return next(self.gen)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3215, in begin
howdyserver |     with self.connect() as conn:
howdyserver |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3251, in connect
howdyserver |     return self._connection_cls(self)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
howdyserver |     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2413, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
howdyserver |     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
howdyserver |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
howdyserver |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3275, in raw_connection
howdyserver |     return self.pool.connect()
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 455, in connect
howdyserver |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1271, in _checkout
howdyserver |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
howdyserver |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 719, in checkout
howdyserver |     rec = pool._do_get()
howdyserver |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
howdyserver |     with util.safe_reraise():
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
howdyserver |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
howdyserver |     return self._create_connection()
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 396, in _create_connection
howdyserver |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 681, in __init__
howdyserver |     self.__connect()
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 905, in __connect
howdyserver |     with util.safe_reraise():
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
howdyserver |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
howdyserver |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
howdyserver |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 636, in connect
howdyserver |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in connect
howdyserver |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
howdyserver |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
howdyserver |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
howdyserver | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
howdyserver |   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
howdyserver | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
howdyserver |   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
howdyserver | 
howdyserver | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
howdyserver | 
howdyserver | ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Can you try to specify in your env file `POSTGRES_SERVER = "database"` (`database` is the name of the service from the docker-compose file)

Comment: Your database container will be available at `database:5433`. You should read about [Docker Compose Networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). Also your database port proxy should be 5432:5432 (or whatever:5432), not 5430:5430 if you want to access it from your machine

Comment: Thank you! The issue was resolved by using the "database" as my postgres_server. Onto the next issue!